# toggle menu button works on index page but not on other pages despite identical code- why?

Tags: html, jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle

Spending hours trying to fix issue I am having with toggle menu button. Works perfectly on small screen on index page- but not working on portfolio & contact page. Despite same code & files (jquery & bootstrap files attached in same order). Any suggestions? Here is the website link: https://www.jophilippa.com/

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="portfolio.html"></a><img src="../img/logo.jpg" class="logo" width="200" height="90" alt="Jo Philippa logo"/>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="../index.html">ABOUT </a> </li>
     <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a> </li> 
    </ul>  
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By quick look at your website & source code, you are linking to your jquery files by relative paths, to be more specific i mean this block of code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>
```

This works at https://www.jophilippa.com/ (as it loads  https://www.jophilippa.com/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js), but won't work at https://www.jophilippa.com/pages/portfolio.html, because that loads https://www.jophilippa.com/pages/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js, which obviously doesn't exist).

Put a / in front of the paths, to make them absolute from the root of website:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: so indeed, basically adding :                      ../        
  This is a directive for the browser to go first one subdirectory up (so go from https://www.jophilippa.com/pages/ to https://www.jophilippa.com/  )  and then descent into the js directory (https://www.jophilippa.com/js), to find, read and execute the .js files, amongst others bootstrap-4.4.1.js .